# showing large data in small area

Tags: winforms

I have a CRM application(winform application),which fetches customer info from db and shows it in a small area using scroll option.But new requirement has come that it will show 65 fields instead of 45 (that was shown earlier) that too in a category wise.Here real problem is i have to show all the data at at a time without scrolling in that small area.

I tried to use pop up but that way Agent cant input data in main form while looking at the pop up box.

So friends do you have any better idea how to achieve this without using any third party controls.

Thanx in advance

Comment: what kind of data, what kind of control do you use? concrete example? Screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You can group the fields in different tabs.

From MS documentation:

To add a tab in the designer
Drag a TabControl from the Windows Forms tab of the Toolbox to the designer.
In the Properties window, click the Add Tab link.
- or -
In the Properties window, click the Ellipsis button (Aa984280.vbellipsesbutton(en-us,VS.71).gif) next to the TabPages property to open the TabPage Collection Editor. Click the Add button.

This way you'll have more space to show the fields, but still using the same area.